# Copy files to rootDir in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to copy files to the rootDir using a task like the one below...

```
task copyFilesToProjectRoot(type: Copy) {
    from (fileTree(dir: *some path*)){
        include '*.*'
    }   
    into('.')
}
```

..but keep getting this exception:

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
        at org.gradle.util.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultHasher.hash(DefaultHasher.java:24)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CachingHasher.hash(CachingHasher.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultFileSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSnapshotter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.OutputFilesSnapshotter.snapshot(OutputFilesSnapshotter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.OutputFilesChangedUpToDateRule.create(OutputFilesChangedUpToDateRule.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CompositeUpToDateRule.create(CompositeUpToDateRule.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$HistoricExecution.calcCurrentState(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$HistoricExecution.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository$ShortCircuitArtifactState.isUpToDate(ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.FileCacheBroadcastTaskArtifactStateRepository$1.isUpToDate(FileCacheBroadcastTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:243)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$300(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:157)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:21)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:233)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:217)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.Execution.execute(Execution.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:177)
        at org.gradle.util.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:55)
        ... 50 more
```

Any ideas on how make this work?

Comment: Do you run this on Windows with daemon enabled? Which Gradle version?

Comment: Latest milestone 6. Just running it from command line in Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work. This is using the underlying ant task.

```
task copyToRoot(){ 
    doLast{ 
    ant.copy(todir:rootDir) {
           fileset(dir:*some path*)
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Working for me... :-)