# How to embed a javaagent in spring boot app using boot gradle plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, javaagents, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am using a javaagent for my spring boot app and currently I am running it via

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar -jar app.jar
```

My project is a gradle project and I want to embed the agent.jar inside the app.jar so that I can run it as

```
java -javaagent:app.jar -jar app.jar
```

It can be done via boot maven plugin as mentioned here - https://jeroendruwe.be/spring-boot-and-new-relic/ but there is no alternative for boot gradle plugin. The closest I find is this - https://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2014/04/08/spring_boot_gradle_newrelic.html, but it does not embed the jar as intended.

Is there anyway it can be done via gradle?

Comment: What's the purpose of that? It's definitely not a best practice to embed infrastructural/util/etc libs inside a microservice, which your spring boot application probably is.

Comment: The purpose is that the spring boot app runs in cloud foundry and we don't have any service for that agent yet. So I want the agent jar to be embedded inside the boot jar, so that we can push it to cf and be done with it without any other config changes.

Answer (score 0):

Can be add as dependency jar from local directory. 'libs' is directory inside your project.

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

Comment: This would put it under BOOT-INF/lib directory which will not load the agent jar during bootstrap. But I want the classes of the agent jar in the topmost directory of the boot jar so Pre-Main instruction in the MANIFEST.MF could find the class.

Comment: @AnindyaChatterjee were you able to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

gradle jar :

```
jar {
manifest{
    attributes "Agent-Class" : "com.......agent.AgentTest"
    //attributes "Premain-Class" : "com.......agent.AgentTest"
        }
    }
```

Althought, I am using to do like this :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String pid = "6236";
    String agentPath = "...";
    VirtualMachine virtualMachine = com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
    virtualmachine.loadAgent("/home/aaa/Code/agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
    virtualMachine.detach();
}
```

Comment: How do I get the pid when I run the app in cf environment? My only objective is to run this in a portable way in different cf environment.

Comment: @AnindyaChatterjee Sorry, I'm not sure about this.Maybe you can try it: build.gradle apply plugin: 'maven' and the detail could be concult https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
java -Xbootclasspath=('your path'/app.jar or 'your path to libs'/agent.jar) -javaagent:'your path'/app.jar -jar 'your path'/app.jar
```

?

Another approach: use jar as dependency and move (or create another one) your premain class in Spring Boot application jar.

Comment: This would place the agent class in BOOT-INF/classes folder inside the boot jar which again is not accessible via -javaagent argument.

Comment: Interesting, -Xbootclasspath (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#i1018570) is an option not for compilation, it is for a running jar, so I don't understand how it could copy jar file anywhere? Why don't you just copy agent jar file to root folder? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565863/copy-files-to-rootdir-in-gradle.

Comment: I did not say anything about bootclasspath. What I meant was, when I create a spring boot jar using gradle build, it will place the premain class inside the BOOT-INF/classes folder and it will place the agent jar in BOOT-INF/libs folder. Your command line arg does not work with this boot jar layout.